# How to find object by id in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this json file:

```
var data = [{
    "id": 0,
    "parentId": null,
    "name": "Comapny",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1235,
            "parentId": 0,
            "name": "Experiences",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 3333,
                    "parentId": 154,
                    "name": "Lifestyle",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 319291392,
                    "parentId": 318767104,
                    "name": "Other Experiences",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}];
```

I need to find object by id. For example if need to find an object with id:319291392, I have to get:

```
{"id": 319291392,"parentId": 318767104,"name": "Other Experiences","children": []}
```

How can I do that?

I tried to use this function:

```
function findId(obj, id) {
    if (obj.id == id) {
        return obj;
    }
    if (obj.children) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
            var found = findId(obj.children[i], id);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it doesn't work as it's an array of objects.

Comment: Your code works  http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/8J4aT/ Used `findIt(data[0], "319291392")`

Comment: Just call the function with `data[0]` for `obj`? Or do you expect multiple top-level elements?

Comment: Thank you guys, I tried also before with data[0] but probably I was doing something wrong. Anyway, right now works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your starting point is an array, you want to invert your logic a bit, starting with the array rather than with the object:

```
function findId(array, id) {
    var i, found, obj;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        obj = array[i];
        if (obj.id == id) {
            return obj;
        }
        if (obj.children) {
            found = findId(obj.children, id);
            if (found) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // <= You might consider null or undefined here
}
```

Then

```
var result = findId(data, 319291392);
```

...finds the object with `id` 319291392.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/voyebebo/1)

Comment: You have completely right! I will use your suggestion! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:-

```
var serachById = function (id,data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(id==data[i].id)
            return data[i];
        if(data[i].children.length>0)
            return serachById(id,data[i].children);
    };
    return null;
}

console.log(serachById(0,data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple solution using object notation.
This solution will work even if you decide to get rid of teh array and use object notation later on. so the code will remain the same.

It will also support the case when you have element with no children.

```
function findId(obj, id) {
    var current, index, reply;

    // Use the object notation instead of index. 
    for (index in obj) {
        current = obj[index];
        if (current.id === id) {
            return current;
        }
        reply = findId(current.children, id);
        if (reply) {
            return reply;
        }

        // If you reached this point nothing was found.
        console.log('No match found');
    }
}

console.log(findId(data, 319291392));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: This is why im using object notation and not index. to skip empty indexes. you are more then right with your comment.

Comment: `for-in` isn't "object notation," if that's what you're referring to. The code above will do a lot of unnecessary work, looking up every (enumerable) property on every object, rather than only processing the appropriate properties. It'll also blow up if any property has the value `undefined` or `null`, on the `current.id === id` line.

Comment: i agree that you can improve it by ass hasOwnProperty but `current.id === id` will be null or defined in case the structure is not in the given format

Answer (score -2):

do it so:

```
for (var obj in arr) {
    if(arr[obj].id== id) {
        console.log(arr[obj]);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. Learning never stops.